# Rails - React Router not keeping its props.children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router, react-rails

I am trying to set up a React Router in Rails for the first time. The links on the router works and changes the hash as expected, but it does not render. I have narrowed down the issue with debugger, and find the following:

- MyRoutes (line 22, before React creates the router) has props.children.
- App (line 6, when rendering) does not have props.children.

What is going on?

```
var Route = ReactRouter.Route,
    Link = ReactRouter.Link;

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    //line 6
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/todo">Todo</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/comment">Comment</Link></li>
        </ul>

        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

$(function(){
  var MyRoutes = (
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
      <Route path="/todo" name="todo" handler={TodoList} />
      <Route path="/comment" name="comment" handler={Comment} />
    </Route>
  );
  //line 22
  ReactRouter.run(MyRoutes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, $("#application").get(0));
  });
})
```

Comment: Were you about to solve this problem? I having the same issue too. What react-router version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [react-router-rails](https://github.com/mariopeixoto/react-router-rails/tree/master/examples/react-router-example) repository. Replace `this.props.children` by `<RouteHandler {...this.props}/>`. But remember you have to "import" RouteHandler as follows: `var RouteHandler = ReactRouter.RouteHandler;`. That should solve it.